# Nginx URL issue with reverse proxy for HTTP request with HTTPS upstream

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

My set up is roughly as follows,

Client ---HTTP---> [NginX in DMZ] ---HTTPS---> [NginX in private space serving Joomla CMS]

I managed to forward the client request to the private NginX and I can access simple test page displaying php info for example. However, all the URLs served by the private NginX use HTTPS protocol.

**Problem:**
Client accessing `http://www.example.com` gets served a page with all the internal links to `https://www.example.com/news/` or `https://www.example.com/image.jpg`

My proxy conf on the public NginX is

```
upstream my-backend {
    server HOSTNAME:443;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://my-backend;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
}
```

I've also written a test.php to display the HTTP header info. It looks correc to me.

```
Host: www.example.com
Remote Address: 10.1.0.5 *Internal IP of my public NginX*
X-Forwarded-For: 2.111.121.220 *Client IP*
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
Server Address: 192.168.5.12 *IP of private NginX*
Server Port: 443
```

This issue appears ubiquitous as it also affect another website hosted running Play Framework on a different private app server (also NginX).

Could you help? Many thanks!!

Comment: Easiest option is to have the system https end to end. The other option is to have the html generate http links, either at the source or by rewriting it somewhere.

Comment: Nginx cannot modify links inside the HTML code generated by the application. You need to change your application so that it generates http links.